# iFrame not being rendered correctly

Tags: html, iframe, geckofx

I have an iFrame used to display a site with a  video.

On Chrome or any other normal browser works perfectly.

When using CustomBrowser i made based on GeckoFX, i inspect the html and only the code for the iFrame is visible, no rendered html with Head , body etc..

The problem is in the iFrame not being rendered in GeckoFX or maybe the content?

**Hardcoded html**

```
 <iframe allowfullscreen allowtransparency="true" class="vzaar-video-player" frameborder="0" height="254" id="iFrameVzaar" mozallowfullscreen name="iFrameVzaar" src="//view.vzaar.com/5263881/player?apiOn=true" title="vzaar video player" type="text/html" webkitallowfullscreen width="448"></iframe>
```

When i render in chrome it loads the whole website with html structure, but not in GeckoFX browser.

Comment: When diagnosing geckofx problems, you want to compare what you see using Firefox, not Chrome. Ideally, compare using the same version of Firefox as the geckofx/xulrunner you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
<iframe allowfullscreen allowtransparency="true" class="vzaar-video-player" frameborder="0" height="254" id="iFrameVzaar" mozallowfullscreen name="iFrameVzaar" src="//view.vzaar.com/5263881/player?apiOn=true" title="vzaar video player" type="text/html" webkitallowfullscreen width="448"></iframe>

<script>
var _theframe = document.getElementById("iFrameVzaar");
_theframe.contentWindow.location.href = _theframe.src;
</script>
```

Comment: It is a bug which is reported to firefox. Still not resolved. =(

Comment: a bug concerning the iFrame, or something relative to the GeckoFX?

Comment: concerning to iframe.

Comment: I copied the rendered code from iFrame , try to use it withouth iFrame, it works on chrome , but on GeckoFx still doesnt work, means there is another problem , not iframe?